# How to use IF statement in Azure ARM template for availability zones?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to add availability zones to my VM creation template and i'm using the code below to achieve this and it works fine.

```
"zones": "[split(string(add(mod(copyIndex(),3),1)), ',')]"
```

But i'm wanting to go further than this. I have a parameter named 'VM Quantity', and i want it so that if this parameter equals 1, don't process this line of code.

So basically, if 'VM Quantity' equals 1, don't add the VM to an availability zone, but if it equals 2 or is greater than 2, run the above code to add it to availability zones.

I've tried varying IF statements and just cannot get this to work at all.

Does anyone know how i would achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add the judge as below:

```
"zones": "[if(lessOrEquals(parameter('VM_Quantity'), 1), '', split(string(add(mod(copyIndex(),3),1)), ','))]"
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Ahhh i didn't think of using 'Less/GreaterOrEquals'. Think we're on the right track but the code above give me some errors.

I got 'The function 'if' takes 3 arguments error, the function 'LessOrEquals' takes 2 arguments error, unrecognized function name 'parameter' error and expected a right parenthesis error.

I think i'd need a 'GreaterOrEquals' rather than less wouldn't i?? i.e If VM_Quantity is greater or equal to 2, run the split(string... part?

Apologises i'm really new to Json/ARM templates and code in general.

Comment: I managed to fix this. Was an argument missing at the end for the 'IF' function but thank you for basically still giving me the answer and setting me on the right path! I've learnt something new and it'll probably stick more in my head just by having to slightly alter what you put. Thanks again!

Comment: @reckless88 Sorry for that, I missed something and update it. But I think my answer guide you in the right way and you can accept it. Otherwise, `lessOrEquals` and `greaterOrEquals` just the different sides of the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this with the following code if anyone ever needs to do anything similar:

```
"zones": "[if(greaterOrEquals(parameters('VM Quantity'),2),split(string(add(mod(copyIndex(),3),1)), ','),'')]"
```

To explain this code, if the parameter 'VM Quantity' is greater than or equal to '2', perform the

```
split(string(add(mod(copyIndex(),3),1)), ',')
```

part of the code, if not, don't do anything.